# In cpp, do I have to always "free" the primitive variables?

Tags: c++

If I have a `function` that declares an `int`, in the end of this `function` I need to "free" that `int` to save memory?

Example:

```
void doSomething() {
    int x = 0;
    // do something with x
    free(x); // needed?
}
```

Comment: no, you only need to delete memory you dynamicly allocated. If a variable runs out of scope which was not allocated by `new` its gone by itself, no need for `delete`

Comment: possible duplicate of [c free memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959289/c-free-memory)

Comment: The "golden" rule: use `delete` / `delete[]`, when you use (respectively) `new` / `new[]`. And if this really is C++ - forget about `free`, `malloc` and family.

Comment: Some answer should state more explicitly whether `free(x)` is just *not needed* (but harmless) or it is even *wrong*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are the memory manegement commandments for you

- Thou shalt ***free*** only what thou hast *malloc'ed* or *calloc'ed*
- Thou shalt ***delete*** only what thou hast *new'ed*
- Thou shalt ***delete[]*** only what thou hast *new[]'ed*
- Thou shalt use **RAII** whenever possible

Comment: also this: `Thou shalt not use free and malloc/calloc in C++`

Comment: @Najzero you smell them, I am virtually hearing them mumble under their breaths

Comment: What kind of English is this  ?

Comment: @AniketInge Why? When working with a library like MPI (parallel library), how would you even get around this?

Answer (score 6):

No. It's an automatic variable, meaning it is deallocated when it goes out of scope.

Also, you rarely use `free()` in C++, it's a C function.

Answer (score 5):

As everyone else has mentioned, no you would not need to free the memory specifically since the variable goes out of scope at the end of the function.

On a slightly different note, however, I came across this page while looking for a way to quickly and cleanly free the memory of primitive variables and later found an incredible way to do this that I didn't realize was a part of C++. For anyone else looking for this answer as well, here it is.

You can actually just use additional set of braces to set the specific scope of variables in C++, so one way to free the memory of "x" in this function without the end of the function would just be encasing the scope of "x" with braces like so:

```
void doSomething() {
    // do something in the start of the function
    {

        int x = 0;
        // do something with x

    } // x is destroyed here

    // do something that doesn't require x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The `int` object has automatic storage duration. It is destroyed at the end of its scope, i.e. when the function ends.

You should not be using `free` in C++ anyway. It is only used when you have used `malloc` to allocate memory, but `malloc` is not often used in C++. Instead, you should be using `new` to dynamically allocate objects. When you have created an object with dynamic storage duration with `new`, use `delete` to destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

## No

`x` is a stack variable and will be deleted automatically when `doSomething()` returns.

Only those objects allocated manually with `malloc()` must be `free()`d (very uncommon in C++). Also do not use `free()` and `malloc()` in C++ - use `new` and `delete` instead.

Answer (score 1):

No you only need to free memory if u have allocate it dynamically using `new` . In this case this variable is in the stack and is destroyed when the functions ends.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to free variables for which you have allocated memory in code. In your example `x` is declared locally, and the program allocates memory for it on the stack. At the end of the function, the variable is automatically destroyed. So you don't need to worry about it.